# Python SysTrayIcon and key listener together?

Tags: python, python-3.x, scripting, keypress

In Windows, I'm making a Python script that creates a tray icon and menu items using [SysTrayIcon](http://www.brunningonline.net/simon/blog/archives/SysTrayIcon.py.html) (with modification to work under Python 3). When a menu item is clicked, code executes. This is perfect.

I have a separate script that uses [pygame](http://www.pygame.org) to listen for a user to provide specific keyboard input. When that input is detected, code executes. This is also perfect.

**However, I want to my script to do both things simultaneously. This does not seem to work.**

What I want is a script that, when activated, creates a tray icon (with menu options) that starts listening for keyboard input. If a certain key combination is pressed (in my case Alt+Shift+F6), some code should execute. When that code is done, the script should return to its listening state. The script must not stop the user from doing other things on the system while it is in this listening mode.

Is what I want even possible?